# c++ constant in library; does not work

Tags: c++, constants

anyone knows why this does not work when I try to include a library with the following declarations:

```
namespace wincabase
{
  const char* SOMESTRING = "xx";
}
```

While this is perfectly fine:

```
namespace wincabase
{
  const int X = 30;
}
```

I get a "multiple definitions" error with gcc for the first case when I link the lib. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

const char* means pointer to const char. This means the pointer itself is **not** constant.

Hence it's a normal variable, so you'd need to use

```
extern const char* SOMESTRING;
```

in the header file, and

```
const char* SOMESTRING = "xx";
```

in one compilation unit of the library.

---

Alternatively, if it's meant to be a **const** pointer to a const char, then you should use:

```
const char* const SOMESTRING = "xx";
```

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the pointer as const, and then pointing it to a string literal defined in the compilation unit, so you'd be duplicating the string literal if you used this in a header file.  What you need to do is declare pointer in the header file, and define the string in a source file in the library.

Header:

```
extern const char* SOMESTRING;
```

In some source file in the library:

```
const char* SOMESTRING = "xx";
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the approach Tobi pointed out:

```
const char* const SOMESTRING = "xx";
```

another alternative is to declare it as a **const** character *array*:

```
const char SOMESTRING[] = "xx";
```

This approach potentially provides the compiler with additional optimization opportunities, such as placing the string in the read-only section of the resulting binary; although it's conceivable the compiler may be able to perform similar optimizations with the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare and define them seprately:

```
Plop.h
======
namespace wincabase
{
   extern const char* SOMESTRING;  // declare
}

Plop.cpp
========
const char* wincabase::SOMESTRING = "xx"; // define
```